# Angular services don't work when moved to separate files

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, pug

I have a problem with my demo MEAN-app (working with it in Cloud9): the app fails to work when I move services to separate files. 
This works:

```
angular.module('locatorApp', [])

var locationListCtrl = function($scope, locatorData, geolocation) {
  $scope.getData = function(position) {
    var lat = position.data.lat;
    var lng = position.data.lon;
    locatorData.locationByCoords(lat,lng)
      .then(function(data) {
        $scope.data = {locations: data.data};
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  geolocation.getPosition($scope.getData);
};

var locatorData = function($http) {
  var locationByCoords = function (lat, lng) {
    return $http.get('/api/locations?lng=' + lng + '&lat=' + lat);
  };
  return {
    locationByCoords : locationByCoords
  };
};

var geolocation = function($http) {
  var geoAPIURL = 'http://ip-api.com/json/?fields=lat,lon,status';
  var getPosition = function(cbSuccess, cbError) {
      $http.get(geoAPIURL).then(cbSuccess, cbError);
  };
  return {
    getPosition : getPosition
  };
};

angular
  .module('locatorApp')
  .controller('locationListCtrl', locationListCtrl)
  .service('locatorData', locatorData)
  .service('geolocation', geolocation);
```

Then I break it into separate files,
app.js:

```
angular
  .module('locatorApp', ['ngRoute'])
  .config(['$routeProvider', config]);

function config($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'home/home.view.html',
      controller: 'homeCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'vm'
    })
    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}
```

home.controller.js:

```
angular
  .module('locatorApp')
  .controller('homeCtrl', homeCtrl);

function homeCtrl(locatorData, geolocation) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.pageHeader = {
    title: 'Locator',
  };

  vm.getData = function(position) {
    var lat = position.data.lat;
    var lng = position.data.lon;
    locatorData.locationByCoords(lat,lng)
      .then(function(data) {
        vm.data = {locations: data.data};
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  geolocation.getPosition(vm.getData);
}
```

geolocation.service.js:

```
angular
 .module('locatorApp')
 .service('geolocation', geolocation);

var geolocation = function($http) {
  var geoAPIURL = 'http://ip-api.com/json/?fields=lat,lon,status';
  var getPosition = function(cbSuccess, cbError) {
      $http.get(geoAPIURL).then(cbSuccess, cbError);
  };
  return {
    getPosition : getPosition
  };
};
```

locatorData.service.js:

```
angular
 .module('locatorApp')
 .service('locatorData', locatorData);

var locatorData = function($http) {
  var locationByCoords = function(lat, lng) {
    return $http.get('/api/locations?lng=' + lng + '&lat=' + lat);
  };
  return {
    locationByCoords : locationByCoords
  };
};
```

links in layout.jade:

```
// files in 'public' folder
script(src='/angular/angular.min.js')
script(src='/lib/angular-route.min.js')

// files in 'app_client' folder 
script(src='/app.js')
script(src='/home/home.controller.js')
script(src='/common/services/geolocation.service.js')
script(src='/common/services/locatorData.service.js')
```

statics in express app.js:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'app_client')));
```

The following error appears:

> Error: [ng:areq]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.1/ng/areq?p0=fn&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined

I googled docs and tutorials, but can't figure out what's wrong with services definitions.

Comment: your service is actually constructed as a factory

Comment: yeah, I figured it out when googled about module structuring, but it should work nevertheless, am I right?

Comment: also `getPosition()` doesn't return anything

Comment: that confuses me too, but it's proven to work in one-file solution (very 1st listing), I think due to using .then()

Comment: but I also tried to rewrite it with return and nothing changed. I did many experiments and everything fails when I pass any services as arguments to homeCtrl function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you use variables before their declarations.

`locatorData` and `geolocation` are defined as function expressions. So, they are undefined before the place of their declaration.

You could change the order of registering the service and defining the function as it was in your original file, that was contained all the code

```
var locatorData = function($http) {
...
};

angular
 .module('locatorApp')
 .service('locatorData', locatorData);
```

or you could use function declaration (not function expression)

```
angular
 .module('locatorApp')
 .service('locatorData', locatorData);

function locatorData($http) {
...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the order of the include scrtipt.
It is looks like you are calling your controller that contains the call for service, even thou you didn't load the service to the page.

```
// files in 'app_client' folder 
script(src='/app.js')
script(src='/common/services/geolocation.service.js')
script(src='/common/services/locatorData.service.js')
script(src='/home/home.controller.js')
```

Answer (score -1):

This way bindings are mirrored across the host object, primitive values cannot update alone using the revealing module pattern.

Try this

geolocation.service.js:

```
angular
.module('locatorApp')
.service('geolocation', geolocation);

 function geolocation ($http) {
    //include these four lines of code
    var MirrorFunc = {
    getPosition : getPosition 
};
  return MirrorFunc;
    //till here 
  var geoAPIURL = 'http://ip-api.com/json/?fields=lat,lon,status';
  function getPosition (cbSuccess, cbError) {
    $http.get(geoAPIURL).then(cbSuccess, cbError);
  }
};
```

similarly for locatorData.service.js:

```
angular
.module('locatorApp')
.service('locatorData', locatorData);

 function locatorData ($http) {
  //include these four lines of code
  var MirrorFunc = {
   locationByCoords : locationByCoords 
 };
 return MirrorFunc ;
//till here 
 function locationByCoords  (lat, lng) {
    return $http.get('/api/locations?lng=' + lng + '&lat=' + lat);
 }  
};
```

You can visit the  John Papa's angular style guide 
https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#services

Comment: thanks for the link!it must be mistake, as the code after return MirrorFunc becomes unreachable

Comment: I made some changes. is there the same problem yet ?

Comment: functions after return MirrorFunc still unreachable